# Funds received from subwallet are not showing

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, sub-address

My wallet has approximately 60,000 subaddresses.

I was running monero-wallet-rpc, and somehow (I think) the program was not able to save the wallet successfully.

When I started monero-wallet-rpc again, my wallet shows the last 10 transactions missing.

I think the wallet file lost some subaddresses.

Is there a way to recover funds from subaddresses? I can’t find any options in Monero GUI.

I also want to know if I can get all 60,000 subaddresses from just recovering the keys from a mnemonic seed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Monero "looks ahead" 200 subaddress indices from the highest subaddress index that it observes it has received an incoming payment to.

Therefore if you ever issue more than 200 subaddresses in a row and none of those receive any funds to them, then you need to force your wallet to scan beyond the subaddress index that it would normally stop looking beyond.

To do this, use the command line Monero wallet (CLI) and type `address new` as many times as necessary to get the wallet to recognize higher subaddress indices. Then type `rescan_bc` to rescan the blockchain for those higher numbered subaddresses.

> I also want to know if I can get all 60,000 subaddresses from a just
>   recovering key from a mnemonic seed

Yes, you can use the `--subaddress-lookahead` option when restoring a wallet from seed using the Monero CLI (command line interface) wallet. E.g. use the command `./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet --subaddress-lookahead 50:70000` to automatically scan the first 70,000 subaddresses for each wallet in each of the first 50 accounts. Note that unlike the GUI, the CLI allows multiple accounts each with multiple subaddresses. If you've only been using the GUI so far, then you'll only have one account.

Comment: Can't you simply regenerate the wallet files with a proper `--subaddress-lookahead` value?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the answer.